# How to get credentials for a RDS read replica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, credentials, aws-secrets-manager, read-replication

I have created a read replica for my Production RDS instance,
However I don't know where can I see the log-in credentials of the replica.

When I go to the secrets manages screen and try to create a new secret the replica instance is not present.

And I dont know the password (It usually displays the password after creating a DB in the console).

how would I get the following Info?
username,
password,
dbname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The credentials are the same as the master node.

It is advised to configure credentials on the master node so that they will be replicate to each read only node.